# If statement giving a phantom number on view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a simple if statement that is placing a phantom number underneath my post. If I remove just the if statement I do not get it anymore. I have determined the statement before and after are not the culprits by deleting them and testing it out. The number it produces are 0 and the number is not significant in my application at all.

I have tried checking source when debugging and it shows up only as text. I have also deleted the part before the `||` and after and tested. They still show up. It's the weirdest thing I have seen.

If you cannot seem to help with why it is doing this is there another way to write this? It is simply saying in pseudocode if the posts body(or content) has a regular expression of the username(tag for user) or if the user that created the post equals the user whose page you are on. then show posts

```
=if post.body =~ /#{@username}/ || post.user == @user
```

Comment: Is this in ERB or HAML or just plain Ruby? Why is it prefixed with `=`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
-if post.body =~ /#{@username}/ || post.user == @user
```

instead of

```
=if post.body =~ /#{@username}/ || post.user == @user
```

`=` will evaluate and display the result whereas `-` would just evaluate the expression.